# How do I make an ISO image out of a folder using Toast?

Tags: iso, cd-burning

I've seen guides on how to do it using Disk Utility and the hdutil command but when I search the net for something that involves using toast, I came up blank.

I've looked around toast (version 11) and I don't see a way of doing it.

Can you help? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do it in Toast specifically?

Comment: because I want to use toast? because I wanna know if it's possible using toast?

Answer (score 1):

Toast has never used .iso format, it uses its own proprietary .toast format.

You can convert back to .dmg or .iso from .toast using something like [DiskImageMounter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DiskImageMounter) but not the other way round.